Type '1' is not assignable to type 'One<T>', where T extends number
I have the following code (nb. this is a simplified version, there are more types allowed than just number or bigint, like time periods, etc.) :
type One<T> = T extends number ? 1 : T extends bigint ? 1n : never;

function one<T extends number | bigint>(arg: T): One<T> {
  switch (typeof arg) {
    case 'number':
      return 1;    // ts error : Type '1' is not assignable to type 'One<T>'
    case 'bigint':
      return 1n;   // ts error : Type '1n' is not assignable to type 'One<T>'
    default:
      throw new TypeError();
  }
}

const n = 123;
const bigN = 123n;

// But here Type '1' is indeed assignable to type 'One<T>' where T extends number :

const a: One<typeof n> = 1; // ok `const a: 1`

const b = one(n);           // ok `const b: 1`
const c = one(bigN);        // ok `const c: 1n`

TS Playground
I don't understand why I get those errors for the return statements, while everything  outside of the function works as expected. Also, if I write return 1 as One<T> or return 1 as any, the error goes away.
Is this a typescript issue ? What am I missing here ?

TS can't analyze extends statements very much at all — they're pretty opaque in terms of analysis and narrowing. And therefore logical conclusions cannot be drawn. When a return statement is reached, the resolved type of One<T> is unknown: it could be 1, it could be 1n, or it could be never. This is a known and very common problem with generics, extends, and varying return types.

As with many issues with generics, it works on the caller side but no the implementation side. The implementation is working with only the abstract generic type, so any analysis is done using principles, not concrete types. When it comes to the caller side, that generic type parameter now has a concrete type, and everything can be calculated fine. You should note that the caller site is only using the stated return type and does not involve the actual return statements at all.

But in the switch block, arg and typeof arg, that is T, are properly resolved, so I would expect One<T> to be resolved as well. And I still don't get why ts sees an error with return 1 but not with return 1 as One<T>.

You want ms/TS#33014 and/or ms/TS#33912, neither of which are implemented currently. See linked q/a for more info.

@DarrylNoakes @jcalz thanks both for the explanations and links, I have searched before asking but I missed those issues, probably because of my lack of typescript vocabulary. That said, I still don't get why return 1 as One<T> works.. CFA and compiler stuff are beyond me right now, but I think will do that except if you have a better suggestion.

Because it is unknown what One<T> will be, so TS does not know if 1 will be assignable to it. However, One<T> will obviously be assignable to One<T>, so that assertion makes it work.
